# Turn this code into a Task to run Asynchronously on another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I am starting to toy with Tasks and async await. So that I get a better handle on how to convert my existing code, I thought I would try to try changing a current method which is run synchronously:

```
private bool PutFile(FileStream source, string destRemoteFilename, bool overwrite)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(destRemoteFilename)) return false;
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(destRemoteFilename);
    if (path == null) return false;
    if (!Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    if (overwrite)
    {
        if (File.Exists(destRemoteFilename)) //delete file if it exists, because we are going to write a new one                 File.Delete(destRemoteFilename);
    }
    else if (File.Exists(destRemoteFilename)) return false;
    using (FileStream dest = File.OpenWrite(destRemoteFilename))
    {
        source.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        source.CopyTo(dest);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have tried to simply change the method to `async`, and dabbled with `Task<bool>` but I'm obviously missing something here as neither of them seem to work.
I have experienced `Type System.Threading.Task<bool>` is not awaitable.

Comment: try this `await Task.Run(() => PutFile(....))`

Comment: have you changed the method signature to private async Task<bool> PutFile(parameters...) ?

Comment: then I get a warning: `this method lacks await operators and will run synchronously`. Not sure where to put the await keyword.

Comment: @Simon: mate, maybe you're making the same mistake I did - trying to learn this technology on-the-fly, as you go. IMO, this is one of those fields where it does pay to take a good read first. E.g., [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam) and [this](http://stephencleary.com/#publications) are awesome resources.

Comment: @Noseratio, yea I'm starting to agree, I've done a bit of reading, but maybe I should do more.... Maybe trying to learn by modifying existing code isnt the answer

Answer (score 6):

You're not calling any async functions in your method, so it would not make any sense to mark it `async` in the first place. However instead of using the sync `CopyTo` you can use the async version `CopyToAsync`.

```
private static async Task<bool> PutFile(FileStream source, string destRemoteFilename, bool overwrite)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destRemoteFilename))
        return false;

    var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(destRemoteFilename);

    if(path == null) 
        return false;

    if(!Directory.Exists(path))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

    if (overwrite)
        if (!File.Exists(destRemoteFilename))
            return false;
        else
            File.Delete(destRemoteFilename);

    using (var dest = File.OpenWrite(destRemoteFilename))
    {
        source.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await source.CopyToAsync(dest);

        return true;
    }
}
```

.. And without async/await:

```
private static Task<bool> PutFile(FileStream source, string destRemoteFilename, bool overwrite)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destRemoteFilename))
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => false);

    var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(destRemoteFilename);

    if(path == null)
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => false);

    if(!Directory.Exists(path))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

    if (overwrite)
        if (!File.Exists(destRemoteFilename))
            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => false);
        else
            File.Delete(destRemoteFilename);

    using (var dest = File.OpenWrite(destRemoteFilename))
    {
        source.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return source.CopyToAsync(dest).ContinueWith(x => true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one q, do i need .NET 4.5, or can this be done in .NET 4? I have an issue with `await source.CopyTo(dest)` : type void is not awaitable

Comment: @Simon, Yes - you need .NET 4.5 for await/async.

Comment: I guess in the meantime I will have to use `Task.Factory.StartNew()`

Comment: @Simon: You can use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` (unless you are on ASP.NET).