# How to implement an async/await version of the System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory method?

Tags: io, directory, async-await

I wonder how I can implement an `async/await` version of the [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx) method in the `System.IO namespace`?

Comment: Check :: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373084/turn-this-code-into-a-task-to-run-asynchronously-on-another-thread

Though always good to do some research on your own, before asking such spoon feed questions

Comment: I have already read that question you are referring to. I'm not interested in running the code asynchronously on another thread, I want to run it with a true asynchronous method call.

Comment: What will you run `Async`, where's the Asynchronous method. `Directory.CreateDirectory` is not an `Async` method

Comment: And that's what's my question is about. 'Directory.CreateDirectory' is a synchronous method and I wonder if it's possible to write code doing the equivalent operation but running asynchronous.

Comment: Now read that link again, answer clearly shows how to do it, by simply returning a Task from a Non Async method, then using `Task.Run` to call it in an `async-await` call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CreateDirectory` is an odd scenario. It would be ideal to have an asynchronous version built-in, particularly for opening/creating directories on a network drive.

Normally, you would be able to P/Invoke an asynchronous Win32 API if the BCL doesn't support async directly. However, in this case, the Win32 API does not actually expose asynchronous APIs for directories. So you'd have to go even lower - probably calling the file system driver directly (all device drivers support async I/O, so that would certainly work).

So, although it's not ideal, you're probably better off *in this case* just making a fake async method, i.e., wrapping the call in `Task.Run`.

On a side note, the Windows Store-style directory APIs are asynchronous. It's possible that they're calling beneath the Win32 API, but I actually rather doubt it - I'd expect they're implemented as fake asynchronous methods.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know how to proceed. A fake asynchronous method isn't a very nice solution in a otherwise fully async application :-/